# Android Google Maps v2: How to add marker with multiline snippet?

Tags: android, google-maps

Does anybody know how to add multiline snippet to Google Maps marker? That's my code for adding markers:

```
map.getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(latLng()).snippet(snippetText)
    .title(header).icon(icon));
```

I want snippet to look like this:

```
| HEADER |
|foo     |
|bar     |
```

but when I'm trying to set snippetText to "foo \n bar", I see just `foo bar` and I don't have any ideas how to make it multiline. Can you help me?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It looks like you will need to create your own "info window" contents to make that work:

1. Create an implementation of `InfoWindowAdapter` that overrides `getInfoContents()` to return what you want to go into the `InfoWindow` frame
2. Call `setInfoWindowAdapter()` on your `GoogleMap`, passing an instance of your `InfoWindowAdapter`

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Popups) demonstrates the technique. Replacing my snippets with `"foo\nbar"` correctly processes the newline. However, more likely, you will just come up with a layout that avoids the need for the newline, with separate `TextView` widgets for each line in your desired visual results.

Comment: If you do use getInfoWindow() to return an entirely customized view, note that there seems to be a bug when using a RelativeLayout for it. I could only get mine to work when switching to a LinearLayout.
I filed a bug report:
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4874

Comment: @Till: Normally, when you use a layout resource with a `RelativeLayout` as the root, when you inflate it, you want to use the three-parameter `inflate()` method, passing in the parent `ViewGroup` and `false` for the last two parameters. However, we are not passed a parent in `getInfoContents()`, so we cannot do that. While I am a bit surprised about a `NullPointerException`, I am not surprised at all that the `RelativeLayout` does not work correctly. I would have expected some of the layout rules for the `RelativeLayout`'s children to be ignored or otherwise misbehave.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm reading the `Maps V2 Chapter` from your 4.6 book and I have a question that is on topic with this question so I think is a good place to ask. I wander if is there any way to set a distinct `infoWindow` for each marker, as long as `setInfoWindowAdapter()` is applied to hole map?

Comment: I've got the code from the sample project working. so I have a custom infowindow but I am stuck on how to add multiple lines still. I've added in extra textviews after title and snippet in the xml layout but how do I get text to appear in the new textviews?

Comment: @cbrook: Call `setText()` on the `TextViews`, no different than `TextViews` in an activity, fragment, `ListView` row, etc.

Comment: That's what I thought but it's not working for me for some reason :/ all I'm doing is putting a second textview in the xml after snippet, then identifying it and setting the text of it within getInfoContents. hmmm maybe I should start a new question?

Answer (score 143):

I have done with easiest way like below:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
```

While **adding** **marker** on **Google Map**:

```
LatLng mLatLng = new LatLng(YourLatitude, YourLongitude);

mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mLatLng).title("My Title").snippet("My Snippet"+"\n"+"1st Line Text"+"\n"+"2nd Line Text"+"\n"+"3rd Line Text").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
```

After that put below code for **InfoWindow** **adapter** on **Google Map**:

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

      @Override
      public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
         return null;
      }

      @Override
      public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

        LinearLayout info = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        info.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        TextView title = new TextView(mContext);
        title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        title.setText(marker.getTitle());

        TextView snippet = new TextView(mContext);
        snippet.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        snippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

        info.addView(title);
        info.addView(snippet);

      return info;
    }
});
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: This should be accepted answer because of `Code Snippet`. Saved my time. even I like `mMap` variable name because that also I haven't changed.

Comment: Warning: I replace "MapsActivity.this" instead of mContext to run with no error.

Answer (score 15):

Building on [Hiren Patel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31629308/2095694) as Andrew S suggested:

```
 mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            Context context = getApplicationContext(); //or getActivity(), YourActivity.this, etc.

            LinearLayout info = new LinearLayout(context);
            info.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            TextView title = new TextView(context);
            title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            title.setText(marker.getTitle());

            TextView snippet = new TextView(context);
            snippet.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            snippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

            info.addView(title);
            info.addView(snippet);

            return info;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Hiren Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31629308/2914140) solution. This code creates a `TextView` from layout, not from zero. One significant difference: if you have **clusters**, you won't see a **void label** when clicking at a cluster.

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    this.googleMap = googleMap
    ...

    // Use this anonymous class or implement GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter.
    googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(object : GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
        override fun getInfoContents(marker: Marker): View? {
            return null
        }

        override fun getInfoWindow(marker: Marker): View? =
            if (marker.title == null)
                null
            else {
                val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_marker, null, false)
                view.label.text = marker.title
    
                view
            }
    })
```

layout_marker.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:textColor="$f0f0f0"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    tools:text="Marker"
    android:background="#00aaee"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Same code, but in Kotlin:

```
    mMap?.setInfoWindowAdapter(object : InfoWindowAdapter {
        override fun getInfoWindow(arg0: Marker): View? {
            return null
        }
        
        override fun getInfoContents(marker: Marker): View {
            val info = LinearLayout(applicationContext)
            info.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
            val title = TextView(applicationContext)
            title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
            title.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)
            title.text = marker.title
            val snippet = TextView(applicationContext)
            snippet.setTextColor(Color.GRAY)
            snippet.text = marker.snippet
            info.addView(title)
            info.addView(snippet)
            return info
        }
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

            // Already two locations
            if (markerPoints.size() > 1) {
                markerPoints.clear();
                mMap.clear();
            }

            // Adding new item to the ArrayList
            markerPoints.add(point);

            // Creating MarkerOptions
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting the position of the marker

            options.position(point);
            if (markerPoints.size() == 1) {
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.markerss)).title("Qtrip").snippet("Balance:\nEta:\nName:");
                options.getInfoWindowAnchorV();
            } else if (markerPoints.size() == 2) {
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.markerss)).title("Qtrip").snippet("End");
            }
            mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

                @Override
                public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                    Context context = getApplicationContext(); //or getActivity(), YourActivity.this, etc.

                    LinearLayout info = new LinearLayout(context);
                    info.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                    TextView title = new TextView(context);
                    title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                    title.setText(marker.getTitle());

                    TextView snippet = new TextView(context);
                    snippet.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                    snippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

                    info.addView(title);
                    info.addView(snippet);

                    return info;
                }
            });
            mMap.addMarker(options);
```