# Add a carriage return into a Google Maps Snippet

Tags: android, google-maps-markers

I'm using google maps apiv2 and I'v added a marker on the map. The marker has a long snippet, so I want to insert some carriage return into the string. I've tried `\n`, `\r` and `System.getProperty("line.separator")`, but nothing happens.

How can I add a CR in a snippet?

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904651/android-google-maps-v2-how-to-add-marker-with-multiline-snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create your own info window `View` using `GoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter`. The default info window implementation seems to remove newlines.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at this today and found that HTML line breaks
`<BR>`work fine.
Some other HTML elements too: `<font size=+1>,<font color=red> & <hr>`
It doesn't seem to like any CSS though.