# How to put window on polyline like in Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

How to put window info on polyline like in Google maps.
I need to put a window info on polyline like in Google maps. 
Image below in red circles.
I noticed some questions in stackoverflow which did not give the expected result. So this question is not duplicate.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google map Android API v2 - InfoWindow on polyline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543904/google-map-android-api-v2-infowindow-on-polyline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this lib https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/

I have tried it works good.

```
IconGenerator iconFactory = new IconGenerator(activity);
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconFactory.makeIcon("Your text")))
            .position("Position that you want")
            .anchor(iconFactory.getAnchorU(), iconFactory.getAnchorV());
```