# How to set a custom marker title for google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

How do I set a styled custom marker title/snippet that includes information and a button? I already have a custom marker icon image set. Now I need a custom pop up window that will contain certain information and a button when the user taps the marker.

Here's something close to what I wanted to achieve.

Custom title/snippet example

[image: Custom title/snippet example]

```
 LatLng huduma_gpo = new LatLng(-1.280694, 36.818277);
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(huduma_gpo).title("Huduma center GPO")).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(marker));

            // For zooming automatically to the location of the marker
            googleMap.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(huduma_gpo , 12.0f) );
```

Comment: didi you try infowidow ?

Comment: Yes it is called infoview search for it https://stackoverflow.com/q/15090148/8089770

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Custom layout design and add it to your Google Map. Here refer this below sample code and customize your design.

**Window Design:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_info_bubble"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/badge"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_lay"
        android:background="@drawable/icn_right_arrow" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_lay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="3dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="title"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/snippet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="45 bays  available"
            android:textColor="@color/green"
            android:textSize="14dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java class for Window Adapter:**

```
public class InfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter, CommonValues, BundleTags {

private View view;

private FragmentActivity myContext;

public InfoWindowAdapter(FragmentActivity aContext) {
    this.myContext = aContext;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_inflate_parking_info_window,
            null);
}

@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

    if (marker != null
            && marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
        marker.hideInfoWindow();
        marker.showInfoWindow();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public View getInfoWindow(final Marker marker) {

    final String title = marker.getTitle();
    final TextView titleUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title));
    if (title != null) {
        titleUi.setText(title);
    } else {
        titleUi.setText("");
        titleUi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    final String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
    final TextView snippetUi = ((TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.snippet));

    if (snippet != null) {

        String[] SnippetArray = snippet.split(SEPARATOR);


        snippetUi.setText(SnippetArray[0]);
    } else {
        snippetUi.setText("");
    }

    return view;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a link to an easy answer only using Title and Snipped:
Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/31629308/7877442