# How to achieve this custom marker?

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I want to create this custom marker and show the detail when user click on the marker. I'm able to create the custom marker with cluster renderer but the problem is the info that extend from the marker. I can't create the info box when user click on the marker.

[image]

Comment: Please enter a example of your code to better explain your case and so that we can help you. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows) for Info Window on Maps.

The below is written on a note there:

> Note: **The info window that is drawn is not a live view**. The view is
>   rendered as an image (using View.draw(Canvas)) at the time it is
>   returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not
>   be reflected by the info window on the map. To update the info window
>   later (for example, after an image has loaded), call showInfoWindow().
>   **Furthermore, the info window will not respect any of the interactivity
>   typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events**. However, you
>   can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as
>   described in the section below.

However, you can use the [onInfoWindowClick](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows#info_window_events) method to detect a click on the info window. **Note: This will click the whole window and leave a click effect on it.**

You can create a custom view to open on the marker click and then interact using the views.

Here's [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50603849/how-to-set-a-custom-marker-title-for-google-maps) to get you started using custom views on Maps.